# Adding support for Scots in Android

Tags: android

Scots is a language spoken in Lowland Scotland and parts of Ulster by 1.5 million people. It is closely related to English and is not similar to Scottish Gaelic.

I would like to add a Scots autocomplete dictionary to Android (one of my clients is Scottish Language Dictionaries, who publish the DSL: http://www.dsl.ac.uk/).  However, Scots seems to be missing from the list of supported languages in Android, so how would I do that?  Do I need to ask somebody to add it to the list?

Furthermore, most Scots write a mixture of standard English and Scots, especially in text messages. Would I need to create only a dictionary of the Scots words that aren't found in English, or would I need to include all English words in the Scots dictionary for Android?

I've no idea how to proceed, so any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Either a custom keyboard or contacting the vendor(s) to start supporting it.

Comment: "Do I need to ask somebody to add it to the list?" -- you're welcome to [file an issue](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs). Just bear in mind that historically Google has not accepted contributions for translating the whole OS, and they will not add it to "the list" until they translate the whole OS to Scots. Even then, it would be for some future version of Android, and even then, you would need to convince manufacturers to ship it. As Shark suggested, your own input method editor could work with your own dictionary and support Scots that way.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! The thing about Scots is that most people in Scotland wouldn't want it as their main interface language (that'd be a fringe thing), but support for Scots words when writing informally would be most welcome. Almost as if it were en_SCO rather than sco_SCO.  It's similar to the need for Schwiizerdütsch in Switzerland.